# How does a seatbelt help in a car crash?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, everyday-life, collision, speed

If you are in a car crash, you will likely have on a seatbelt because they are supposed to help you from getting injured/harmed. But, I don't think they are that much of a help. First of all, say you crashed at like 56 mph. A seat belt will not restrict the speed you are moving at very much, seeing as in a car you can easily move forward with a seatbelt on, and at most it would probably only slow you down like 1-3 mph, which isn't very much, seeing as you'll still crash at about 54 mph. And, if your are flying through the air, the seat belt eventually wont have enough left to keep unraveling and will abruptly stop, which I think could lead to internal damage seeing as you are going about 54 mph. Also, if the seatbelts safety precautions kick in, it will squeeze in on you, and while that will prevent a lot of external damage, that could possibly break a rib or damage/injure internal organs which could lead to death. So I want to know how seatbelts are supposed to help you in a car crash.(this is from personal experience, I do not expect you to have experienced the same seatbelt as me, and I am sorry if I don't know much about seat belts, this question is purely from experience.

Comment: Your seatbelt does not 'unravel' in a crash - it locks tight holding you in position as the car crumple zones absorb lots of energy and slow the passenger compartment (with you attached) down slowly, limiting the maximum forces on your body. Your idea of how the seatbelt works are incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried pulling quickly on a seatbelt?

Comment: how do you think you clip in a seat belt?

Comment: you pull it, therefore unraveling it.

Comment: It unravels when you pull it slowly yes but try pulling it quickly and it locks in place which is crucial for when experiencing a crash.

Comment: a seat belt only doesn't unravel if you fully unravel it.

Comment: Yes, but I talked about seat belts stopping quickly in the question.

Comment: Also, most seat belts are quite easy to pull fast, most people pull quite fast when clipping a seatbelt in.

Comment: See https://auto.howstuffworks.com/car-driving-safety/safety-regulatory-devices/seatbelt4.htm for example on how the seatbelt pretensioner works - in the case a threshold acceleration (crash) is sensed, your seatbelt will retract very quickly and lock you into place.

Comment: I do not understand why this was downvoted, The physics of the question is in the equation $\Delta p = \int_0^1 F\cdot dt \approx \langle F \rangle \Delta t$ so that for a given momentum (impulse) change the force effecting that change, here the stop, is inversely dependent on the stopping time. The seat belt stretches and takes longer to stop the body during which the engine is crashing in the passenger compartment and would crush the driver if not for the seat belt. As long as the seat belt is faster than the engine were to reach the moving body if not for the belt, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A seatbelt locks in place once it reaches some g-force the indicates it may be in a collision (you'll notice this when you break hard or try to put on a seatbelt when you're turning sharply).

You're right that you're going to need to slow down to 0 mph no matter what. The maximum force on your body during that process can be found using $\Delta p = F \cdot \Delta t $ if you use a simple model of constant decleration.

You can slow down with the seatbelt, which will stretch even when it locks, or you can slow down by hitting the rigid dashboard which has very little give.

The seatbelt greatly reduces the maximum force by spreading out the force over time, and also prevents the force from being applied to your head from the dashboard.

Comment: thanks for showing me a seatbelt at least helps a bit.

Comment: imo a 5-fold reduction in force is more than just "a bit", but no one's gonna stop you from being skeptical about seatbelts I guess

Answer (score 3):

The job of the seatbelt is to make your stopping distance the same as the car's stopping distance (the latter determined by its crumple zone). Unrestrained by a seatbelt, your stopping distance would be determined by the objects you impact in front of you during the crash (steering wheel, dash, windshield, etc.)

According to the following site, with a seat belt your stopping distance would probably be 4 or 5 times greater than if you had no seatbelt.

See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/seatb.html

From the work energy principle

$$F_{ave}d=-\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Where $F_{ave}$ = the average impact force you experience, $d$= your stopping distance, $m$ = your mass, and $v$= your velocity just prior to impact which becomes zero.

If $d$ is, say, 4 times greater with the seatbelt than without it, that means the average impact force you experience will be one fourth of that you would experience without the seatbelt.

Though the seatbelt won't necessarily prevent you from getting injured, it could be the difference between surviving or not surviving a crash.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The seatbelt behaves very different for small and large acceleration. If you move slowly it extends quite a bit, but if you accelerate more the device holding it stops it from slipping and getting longer  and hold you back. You can try it out by just moving the bellt fast, when you put it on.
There are a number of good movies in you tube who explain the working of seatbelts

Comment: thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The seat belt plays an important role, but it isn't the only thing keeping you from harm. When you crash, it is important to minimize the force and pressures on you.

Normally you think of a car as fairly rigid. If you slap the dashboard, it doesn't give. Except perhaps the seat is cushy.

This is a simplification. In a crash, the forces are much bigger than normal. The car does bend. Designers make the passenger compartment strong and rigid, so it doesn't bend even in most crashes. The front is designed to crumple and absorb the impact. This means the passenger compartment is slowed to a stop over the crumple distance, rather than instantly. This is a lower force over a longer distance, rather than a higher force over a shorter distance.

Inside the passenger compartment, air bags deploy during the crash. They only stay inflated a short time. But that short time is enough for the passenger compartment to stop. The idea is that you hit a pillow instead of the steering wheel. It needs to be an extremely firm pillow, because you hit it hard. The important point is that it is a broad surface that conforms to your body, rather than a rigid steering wheel or dashboard. This spreads the force over your body, instead of concentrating it all in one spot. The makes a lower pressure over a larger area, rather than a higher pressure in a smaller area.

It is something like cutting a steak with a knife. A sharp knife has a narrow edge. It cuts with a small force. A dull knife has a broader edge. The same force does less to the steak.

Seat belts also help. They lock during a crash, and stretch very little. They keep you on the seat, so you are in the right position for air bags to protect you. Seat belts are wide. They distribute the force as they hold you.

In a roll over accident, they keep you from being thrown from the car. This is usually fatal.

In cars without air bags, seat belts are your only line of defense. If you are thrown around inside the car, you can hit things at awkward angles. Being thrown into the dashboard head first can break your neck.